# Encountered an error executing step ETL-file-load in job ETL-Load

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-batch

I am getting this error on the Heroku server but it is totally working locally.

This is  controller which is getting CSV file from a form and trying to store in the resource folder.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/import-csv")
    public ModelAndView uploadCSV(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException, JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {
        logger.info("Entering into import-csv controller");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("listId"));
        try {
            String listId = request.getParameter("listId");
            logger.info("id is : {}",id);
            String path = new ClassPathResource("tempUpload/").getURL().getPath();
            logger.info("path : {}",path);
            File fileToImport = new File(path + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
            logger.info("full path : {}", fileToImport.toString());

            System.out.println("iside cotmt:" + "file:" + fileToImport.getAbsolutePath());


            Map<String, JobParameter> maps = new HashMap<>();
            maps.put("time", new JobParameter(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            maps.put("fullPathFileName", new JobParameter(fileToImport.getAbsolutePath()));
            maps.put("listId", new JobParameter(listId));
            JobParameters parameters = new JobParameters(maps);
            JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, parameters);


            logger.info("JobExecution: {}" ,jobExecution.getStatus());

            logger.info("Batch is Running...");
            userService.setListofUserSave(listId);
            logger.info("Exiting from import-csv controller");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error while uploading csv file");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/view?id=" + id);
    }
```

This is the item reader taking the path of CSV file that is stored temporarily in the resource folder.

```
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public FlatFileItemReader<User> itemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters[fullPathFileName]}") String pathToFile) {
        logger.info("file path inside spring batch config: {}", pathToFile);
        FlatFileItemReader<User> flatFileItemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        flatFileItemReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(pathToFile));
        flatFileItemReader.setName("CSV-Reader");
        flatFileItemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        flatFileItemReader.setLineMapper(
        new DefaultLineMapper<User>() {{
            setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
                setNames(new String[]{"name", "email"});
            }});
            setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<User>() {{
                setTargetType(User.class);
            }});
        }}) ;
        return flatFileItemReader;
    }
```

But it is showing this error in logs:

```
Apr 02 04:11:31 demo-letter app/web.1 2020-04-02 11:11:30.802  INFO 4 --- [o-57213-exec-10] c.e.demo.Configration.SpringBatchConfig  : file path inside spring batch config: /app/file:/app/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/tempUpload/csvtesting.csv
Apr 02 04:11:31 demo-letter app/web.1 2020-04-02 11:11:30.805 ERROR 4 --- [o-57213-exec-10] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step ETL-file-load in job ETL-Load
Apr 02 04:11:31 demo-letter app/web.1 
Apr 02 04:11:31 demo-letter app/web.1 org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
Apr 02 04:11:31 demo-letter app/web.1   at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:153) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
Apr 02 04:11:31 demo-letter app/web.1   at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ebb633d0.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
Apr 02 04:11:31 demo-letter app/web.1   at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
Apr 02 04:11:31 demo-letter app/web.1   at 

org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
.
.
.
Apr 02 04:11:31 demo-letter app/web.1   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_242-heroku]
Apr 02 04:11:31 demo-letter app/web.1 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode): file [/app/file:/app/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/tempUpload/csvtesting.csv]
Apr 02 04:11:31 demo-letter app/web.1   at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doOpen(FlatFileItemReader.java:257) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
Apr 02 04:11:31 demo-letter app/web.1   at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:150) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
Apr 02 04:11:31 demo-letter app/web.1   ... 84 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error:

```
Apr 02 04:11:31 demo-letter app/web.1 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode): file [/app/file:/app/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/tempUpload/csvtesting.csv
```

I believe your resource is being resolved from the classpath, and not on the file system. You issue is here:

```
String path = new ClassPathResource("tempUpload/").getURL().getPath();
```

which should be:

```
String path = new FileSystemResource("/absolute/path/to/tempUpload/").getURL().getPath();
```